# Google maps v3 longitude issue

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

After having integrated the dealer locator with Google Maps v3, I found some places got a problem especially in Canada when longitude start with a negative value.

**Example**

```
Red Deer, AB, Canada
Lat : 52.268112
Long : -113.811239
```

Google Maps will point to somewhere in the Pacific Ocean.

Dealer page : [link](http://motobatt.mices.com.my/dealer)

Source code : https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: Those coordinates seem fine to me when I simply create a map with that as the coordinates.  Instead of linking to an external site with a huge amount of code, edit your question to include the minimum code required to demonstrate the problem

Comment: @duncan this page that im working with http://motobatt.mices.com.my/dealer

Comment: so initially that page seemed to correctly load up at Red Deer (after I'd searched for it).  Then it refreshed to that point which seems to be on the equator.  Are you sure your data is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seems to be a problem with coordinates. For me its plotting at Red Deer exactly. How are you loading these coordinates (comma separated text or iterating through an array)?. Seems like something going wrong with the data being passed. I too faced similar issue when passed data as comma separated which contained some odd pairs.

Comment: i refer this page almost all code and data structure is same https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: "Seems like something going wrong with the data being passed" after i check when php pass all data i found some data is failed to pass(then cause google map failed to plotting), so after convert all data using 'htmlentities()' problem solve.